# Getting a pending transaction without its hash

Tags: web3.py, pending-transactions

With web3py, when I do

```
a = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(address)
b = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(address, block_identifier='pending')
```

I consistently have `a = 100` and `b = 101`, say (the pending transaction was dispatched to Infura/Rinkeby).

But I cannot see that transaction in

```
w3.eth.get_block('pending', full_transactions=True)
```

-- why?

Knowing the txn hash, I can see it on `https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/[hash]` with the note "This txn hash was found in our secondary node and should be picked up by our indexer in a short while.", and I can retrieve it using `w3.eth.get_transaction([hash])`

but it never shows up as a pending transaction here `https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/txsPending?a=[from_address]`.

How can I get at the pending transaction without knowing the hash?